# Laravel Auditing - How To Get Specific Column Using Eloquent Model Method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, audit-trail, laravel-auditing

I'm using Laravel Auditing Package to trace changes on my models.
I want to get a specific column of the foreign key in it's primary table before recording the events (create, update, delete) in the audit table.

There is a way the package helps get all the attribute of the foreign key, it's called Audit Transformation but it generates an error for me when displaying the details in the table i want to know if there's any eloquent model method to get the specific column info i need instead of using **`getattribute()`** method which gets the entire row of the **`item_id`**.

**Audit Transformation Method**

```
public function transformAudit(array $data): array
{

    if (Arr::has($data, 'new_values.item_id')) {
        $data['old_values']['item_name'] = Item::find($this->getOriginal('item_id'));
        $data['new_values']['item_name'] = Item::find($this->getAttribute('item_id'));
    }

    return $data;
}
```

This is how it's stores in the database ephasis on the **`item_name`**.

```
{"item_id":"1","qty_received":"2","delivered_by":"John",
"received_by":"Abi","supplier":"Stores","date":"2019-11-26","item_name":{"item_id":1,"item_name":"Toner","colour":"Black","status":"Active",
"created_at":"2018-10-25 17:55:26","updated_at":"2018-10-25 17:55:26"}}
```

And this is the Item table schema
[image: Item Schema]

So in my scenario i'd want to store the **`item_name`** as **`Toner`** not the entire row of the **`item_id`**
Any suggestion will be welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: getAttribute doesn't return an entire row, it returns a single value.  What returns an entire row (actually an entire model) is Item::find...

Comment: @Devon thanks for clearing that up but how best do you think i can get the the item_name then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `->item_name->item_name` after the function of Find.

```
 if (Arr::has($data, 'new_values.item_id')) {
    $data['old_values']['item_name'] = Item::find($this->getOriginal('item_id'))->item_name->item_name;
    $data['new_values']['item_name'] = Item::find($this->getAttribute('item_id'))->item_name->item_name;
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the redundancy and I think it's always a good idea to make sure find actually found something before relying on a property, otherwise, your app will crash.

Comment: Its okay to add it infront of Find(). Try it first and let me know if it bring any errors. You get all those extra data because you have join your models,

Comment: @Gabby It works only if i add it to the new_values but if i use it for the both it doesn't work. Hey here's another question what if i want to add extra columns for instance the colour, how do i go about it?

Comment: @Nii what output does it give in old_value? To add extra column just repeate the two line with changing **item_name** to **color** within the same **IF** statement